# WSS : No site collection at web application root

Tags: sharepoint, wss

From : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288905.aspx?ppud=4

> Do not use “/*” to indicate wildcard managed sites at the root of the site collection. Using this wildcard prevents a site being created at the root of the Web application. Many SharePoint features rely on having a site collection at the root of the Web application, and if this is missing, these features will not work correctly. For example, Explorer View will not work for a document library.

I'm wondering what problems may occur if there is no site collection at the root of a web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Microsoft state that problems will occur then don't do it. Regardless of possible errors, the web application will **not be supported by Microsoft**. If things go wrong you won't be able to get help. IMHO this makes it not worth even considering.